# require() not working - NGINX PHP configuration problem

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

**SOLVED: File was not correctly named (header.php instead of layout.php)**

I'm currently experimenting with NGINX and PHP. I try to require some files, but unfortuantely require is only looking for things like this: /path/to/root/subdir/index.php

The relevant part of the configuration is the **PHP Playground Area**. Please have a look. Is there something wrong with the config, so that it is just looking for index.php files for includes with PHP?

The nginx error log just displays: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(layout.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/index.php on line 7`

I checked my structure. The required layout.php file is placed in the same directory under var/www/html/php.

**Code where I try to require:**

```
<?php

echo "<title>Playground</title>";

echo "Hello World";

require('layout.php');
require ('footer.php');
```

**Config**:

```
server {

# ======================
# BASIC CONFIGURATION
# ======================

listen 80;
server_name 172.17.1.75;
root /var/www/wordpress/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
#try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
rewrite_log on;

# ======================
# WORDPRESS WEBSITE
# ======================

location / {
    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}

# ======================
# PHP PLAYGROUND
# ======================

location /php {
root /var/www/html/;
# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}

# ======================
# ORDER PORTAL
# ======================

location ^~ /laravel {
alias /var/www/html/public;
try_files $uri $uri/ @laravel;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

}

location @laravel {
    rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
}

# ======================
# PROXY PASS AREA
# ======================

# Proxy to holiday and work time management
location /azm {
    proxy_pass http://172.17.1.28:8081;
}

# Proxy to old shop
location /shop2 {
    proxy_pass http://172.17.1.28:8080;
}

# Proxy to order portal without laravel
location /portal {
    proxy_pass http://172.17.1.28;
}

}
```

**File structure:**

/var/www/html -> laravel part and php playground
/var/www/wordpress -> wordpress part

[image: structure of the html directory]

Comment: the error = 404. The file you try to pass can't be found (whether related to nginx or not). Just to be sure, can you include your code that does the `require`?

Comment: I also wouldn't nest the the ```~ \.php {}``` section as it makes the configuration a lot less readable. I think it will allow you to see you don't try_files in the php playground section.

Comment: @treyBake I attached the code to the post.

Comment: and to be extra pedantic - can you screenshot the file-tree (or the relevant part of the tree)

Comment: Check the *permissions* of `/var/www/html/php/layout.php`, too. Not just its existence.

Comment: @treyBake structure attached.

Comment: @ceejayoz does 404 == 403 in nginx? o.O

Comment: I'm not seeing a layout.php file there? o.O

Comment: @ceejayoz permission of layout.php is set to rwx for group (www-data) and owner (www-data). nginx and php fpm have the same user

Comment: @glembo As treyBake points out, your screenshot conclusively shows there **isn't** a `layout.php` in the `php` folder.

Comment: @treyBake oh god. shame on me. that was the problem. should stop work for today. thanks a lot guys

Comment: If you've solved your problem either post an answer and accept it or delete the question. We don't do "SOLVED" in the titles here

Comment: It happens more oft than ya think :) sometimes it helps to really break it down into what feels like stupid things to really see the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED: File was not correctly named (header.php instead of layout.php)**

As treyBake discovered the file was not named correctly. Instead of header.php I used layout.php.